# Apache PIG - set date of current row as next records date

Tags: apache-pig

In Pig, I have requirement to set avail_until as next records' avail_since given a particular id and default it to 9999-12-31 for the last record of a given id. I'm starting out by ordering the data by ID and then Avail_Since but am stuck after that. I think I may need an over/stitch/lead/lag function but not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Input Data:

```
ID       AVAIL_SINCE    AVAIL_UNTIL
1        19-Jan-00      31-Dec-99
1        11-Jun-00      31-Dec-99
1        4-Aug-00       31-Dec-99
1        19-May-01      31-Dec-99 
2        5-May-02       31-Dec-99 
2        8-Apr-03       31-Dec-99 
3        10-Jun-00      31-Dec-99 
3        31-Oct-00      31-Dec-99 
3        29-Dec-00      31-Dec-99
```

Required Result:

```
ID       AVAIL_SINCE    AVAIL_UNTIL
1        19-Jan-00      11-Jun-00
1        11-Jun-00      4-Aug-00
1        4-Aug-00       19-May-01
1        19-May-01      31-Dec-99
2        5-May-02       8-Apr-03 
2        8-Apr-03       31-Dec-99
3        10-Jun-00      31-Oct-00
3        31-Oct-00      29-Dec-00
3        29-Dec-00      31-Dec-99
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    --load file    
    A = load 'pdemo/sample1'
    using PigStorage(',')
    as(id:int,date1:chararray,date2:chararray);

    --Generate alternate record except last row.
    B = RANK A; 
    C = foreach B generate rank_A-1,date1,date2;
    J = join B by rank_A,C by $0;
    result = foreach J generate B::id as ID,B::date1 as AVAIL_SINCE,C::date1 as AVAIL_UNTIL;


    --Extract the last row
    grp = group B all;
    maxr = foreach grp generate MAX(B.rank_A);
    ij1 = join B by rank_A,maxr by $0;
    last_row = foreach ij1 generate B::id as ID,B::date1 as AVAIL_SINCE,B::date2 as AVAIL_UNTIL;

    Final_result = union result,last_row;
```

Hope this will help!!!

Comment: hi ankur, thank you so much for this! i'm definitely going to try and incorporate this into my issue. however, and i'm sorry, I forgot to include that i have multiple id's so i need to include a group by id somehow into this. would you be able to edit the answer slightly so that it can perform the same function grouped by id's?